# Implementing getAuthToken in AccountManager using coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am having a problem implementing getAuthToken.

```
   override fun getAuthToken(
        response: AccountAuthenticatorResponse,
        account: Account,
        authTokenType: String,
        options: Bundle
    ): Bundle? {
        val password = AccountManager.get(context).getPassword(account)
        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job())
        scope.launch {
            val user = getNetworkService().login(account.name, password)
            val token = Gson().toJson(user)
            // ERROR: return is not allowed here
            return Bundle().apply {
                putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
                putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
                putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, token)
                Timber.i("Got auth token and bundle is $this")
            }
        }
    }
```

When I launch the coroutine scope, I cannot return the token I get after the network call. There is an error, 'Return not allowed here'. How can I correctly return the authToken?

Comment: You cannot return result of a suspenable block of code, without making a function suspend. Probably you have to do a runBlocking. Which is not great for production.

Comment: `runBlocking` is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to perform the asynchronous login request outside `getAuthToken`.

In `getAuthToken` all I do is to fetch the existing token else return `null`.

```
    // This method runs whenever the authToken is invalid or null
    // The first time it runs is after you add an account to accountManager
    // Use this method to fetch the token from the network/server and return it in a bundle
    // Do not call accountManager.setAuthToken(token) directly in the application
    override fun getAuthToken(
        response: AccountAuthenticatorResponse,
        account: Account,
        authTokenType: String,
        options: Bundle
    ): Bundle? {
        val authToken: String? = AccountManager.get(context).peekAuthToken(account, accountType)
        return authToken?.let { token ->
            Bundle().apply {
                putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
                putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
                putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, token)
                Timber.i("Got auth token, bundle is $this")
            }
        }
    }
```

I had to neglect all the comments above the method.

I then set the `authToken` directly from register and login fragments.

This is the extension function for adding an account.

```
fun Fragment.addAccount(email: String, password: String, token: String) {
    val am = AccountManager.get(activity)
    val account = Account(email, getAccountType())
    am.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null)
    am.setAuthToken(account, accountType, token)
    am.setUserData(account, userData, token)
}
```